# How to read data in JSON format array of string data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am newbie in JavaScript. I am trying to read JavaScript data in JSON format.

**data.json:**

```
[[Hi, Helo, Mort,Top, Est, Fist]]

name: { categories: []}
```

**Reading data and assiging to name:**

```
$.getJSON('data.json', function(data) {
  name.categories = name.toString();
});
```

But it does not work for me. How can I read it properly?

Answer (score 2):

```
var items = [];
$.getJson('data.json', function(data) {
  $.each(data, function(index, value) {
    items.push(value);
  })
})
```

Hope it will help for you.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to recommend you to check your json data.

A well-formed json data with string's arrays could be:

```
["Hi", "Hello", "Test"]
```

If you need help to validate your json data, you might use this link: http://pro.jsonlint.com/

About your question, the Pankaj Gupta's answer is a very good choice to start.

Don't forget to use semicolons at the end of the javascript sentence.

```
var items = [];
$.getJson("data.json", function(data)
{
    $.each(data, function(index, value)
    {
        items.push(value);
     });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

1.You replace `name.toString()` to `data`. Then it will work.

```
var name = {
  categories: []
};
$.getJSON('data.json', function(data) {
  name.categories = data;
});
```

2.Also, You can set through Helper object. `Helper.setArray(name.categories, data);` instead of `name.categories = data;`. Usually, I use helper for parsing and other purposes.

```
var Helper = {
  clearArray: function(arr) {
    if (arr && Array.isArray(arr)) {
      arr.length = 0;
    }
  },
  pushArray: function(arr1, arr2) {
    if (arr1 && arr2 && Array.isArray(arr1)) {
      arr1.push.apply(arr1, Array.isArray(arr2) ? arr2 : [arr2]);
    }
  },
  setArray: function(arr1, arr2) {
    this.clearArray(arr1);
    this.pushArray(arr1, arr2);
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

First you need to create the [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript)array object.

- After that you have to loop the [json](/questions/tagged/json) data and store one by one push into the array object.

**Example:**

```
var categories = [];
var jsonobj;
$.getJSON('data.json', function(data) {
  jsonobj = data;
});
for (i in obj) {
  var temp = [];
  temp.push(obj[i].'jsondata');
}
```

Hope this is answer your question. You can refer this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/umeshpatil86/qLypg/):

Comment: The code above is incomplete compared to the fiddle.

Comment: @RickCalder : I agree Rick. I just paste the fiddle link for reference purpose. Not for an actual answer.